# Does css3 allow mathematic calculation

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a parent element and a child element like this

```
<parent element>

    <...>

         <...>

               <child element></child element>

         </...>

     <...>

</parent element>
```

I want to make the child element to receive the width of the parent/2.

I am wondergint, does CSS3 allow using something like:

```
child{
    width:parent().parent().parent().width/2 + "px"
}
```

I cant use jquery and I cant add any additional code to the HTML, I only have access to CSS file. Is this possible?

Comment: Why not `width: 50%` for the first child?

Comment: Didnt work. I use position absolute with the <...> elements. I really need to use math.

Comment: This is only possible if the element between the _parent_ and _child_ have a static position. Instead, there might be other ways to solve this if you give us a real case scenario, where we see how all these elements interact, together with how the _parent_ relate to the viewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not exactly, but you can achieve something similar mixing [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) and `calc`:

Here's an example using a parent's scope's variables

```
your_parent_element_selector{
  --ParentWidth: 100vw;
  width: var(--ParentWidth);
}

your_parent_element_selector /* ... */ your_child_selector{
  width: calc(var(--ParentWidth) / 2);
  /*no need for units for those simple calculations*/
  /*this variable is accessible because the child is within
  the parent's scope*/
}
```

Here's an example using "global" scope variables

```
:root{
  /*[...]*/
  --ThisSpecificParentWidth: 100vw;
}

your_parent_element_selector{
  width: var(--ThisSpecificParentWidth);
  /*accessible bc everything is within :root's scope*/
}

your_parent_element_selector /* ... */ your_child_selector{
  width: calc(var(--ThisSpecificParentWidth) / 2);
}
```

Something really interesting about `calc` is that you can achieve really complex calculations such as : `calc((100vw - 2em) / 2 + 10vh)`.

As [CSS variables](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/--*) are just custom properties, you can totally store calculation results (be careful with scope) like so : `--prop: calc((100vw - 2em) / 2 + 10vh - (var(--margin) * 2));`

Comment: Goot alternative the problem is that I cant rewrite the parent code to add width:var... I can only append style to the css sheet.

Comment: sadly it is not feasible without a modification, CSS is not that flexible.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `calc` as correctly mentions in other answers.

> The calc() CSS function can be used anywhere a , ,
>   , , , or  is required. With calc(), you
>   can perform calculations to determine CSS property values.

CSS cals support the following arithmetic operations:

- Addition.
- Subtraction.
- Multiplication. At least one of the arguments must be a .
- Division. The right-hand side must be a .

Example:

```
width: calc(50% + 50px);
```